# Multiple .mdf files for SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database

I created a database with 3 `.mdf` files and one `.ndf` file and a log file by mistake.

```
CREATE DATABASE [Test] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'Test_Data01', FILENAME = N'C:\MSSQLDSS\PROD01\TestDB\Test_Data01.mdf' , SIZE = 16724800KB , MAXSIZE = 30818304KB , FILEGROWTH = 524288KB ), 
( NAME = N'Test_Data02', FILENAME = N'C:\MSSQLDSS\PROD01\TestDB\Test_Data02.mdf' , SIZE = 15676224KB , MAXSIZE = 30818304KB , FILEGROWTH = 524288KB ), 
( NAME = N'Test_Data03', FILENAME = N'C:\MSSQLDSS\PROD01\TestDB\Test_Data03.mdf' , SIZE = 15781120KB , MAXSIZE = 20578304KB , FILEGROWTH = 524288KB ), 
( NAME = N'Test_Data04', FILENAME = N'C:\MSSQLDSS\PROD01\TestDB\Test_Data04.ndf' , SIZE = 16305408KB , MAXSIZE = 20578304KB , FILEGROWTH = 524288KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'Test_Log01', FILENAME = N'C:\MSSQLDSS\PROD01\TestDB\Test_Log01.ldf' , SIZE = 544704KB , MAXSIZE = 68706304KB , FILEGROWTH = 262144KB )
GO
```

I created many tables and realised my mistake. Is it possible to update the database to have only one `.mdf` and change the other 2 `.mdf` files to `.ndf`?

Thanks

Comment: If you "simply" want to rename the files, you'll need to detach the database, rename, and then reattach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename database files by following the same procedure as [moving database files to a new location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-file-and-filegroup-options?view=sql-server-ver15#f-moving-a-file-to-a-new-location).

Execute `ALTER DATABASE...MODFY FILE` for each file:

```
USE master;

ALTER DATABASE Test 
    MODIFY FILE (NAME = N'Test_Data02', FILENAME = N'C:\MSSQLDSS\PROD01\TestDB\Test_Data02.ndf');
ALTER DATABASE Test 
    MODIFY FILE (NAME = N'Test_Data03', FILENAME = N'C:\MSSQLDSS\PROD01\TestDB\Test_Data03.ndf');
ALTER DATABASE Test 
    MODIFY FILE (NAME = N'Test_Data04', FILENAME = N'C:\MSSQLDSS\PROD01\TestDB\Test_Data04.ndf');
GO
```

Set database OFFLINE (requires exclusive database access):

```
ALTER DATABASE Test SET OFFLINE;
GO
```

Rename physical files with extension ndf.

Set database ONLINE:

```
ALTER DATABASE Test SET ONLINE;
GO
```

GO

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, to the Method Dan shows, you can detach the database, rename, and then reattach with the correct names. This is for my environment (which is running on Linux), but you get the idea:

Initial Create:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE [Test] ON PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'Test_Data01', FILENAME = N'/mnt/WDBlue/Test_Data01.mdf' , SIZE = 16724800KB , MAXSIZE = 30818304KB , FILEGROWTH = 524288KB ), 
( NAME = N'Test_Data02', FILENAME = N'/mnt/WDBlue/Test_Data02.mdf' , SIZE = 15676224KB , MAXSIZE = 30818304KB , FILEGROWTH = 524288KB ), 
( NAME = N'Test_Data03', FILENAME = N'/mnt/WDBlue/Test_Data03.mdf' , SIZE = 15781120KB , MAXSIZE = 20578304KB , FILEGROWTH = 524288KB ), 
( NAME = N'Test_Data04', FILENAME = N'/mnt/WDBlue/Test_Data04.ndf' , SIZE = 16305408KB , MAXSIZE = 20578304KB , FILEGROWTH = 524288KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'Test_Log01', FILENAME = N'/mnt/WDBlue/Test_Log01.ldf' , SIZE = 544704KB , MAXSIZE = 68706304KB , FILEGROWTH = 262144KB )
GO
```

Detach database:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE Test SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO

EXEC sys.sp_detach_db N'Test';
```

Rename files:

```sh
mv /mnt/WDBlue/Test_Data02.mdf /mnt/WDBlue/Test_Data02.ndf
mv /mnt/WDBlue/Test_Data03.mdf /mnt/WDBlue/Test_Data03.ndf
```

Reattach with new file names:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE [Test]
    ON PRIMARY (NAME = N'Test_Data01', FILENAME = N'/mnt/WDBlue/Test_Data01.mdf'), 
               (NAME = N'Test_Data02', FILENAME = N'/mnt/WDBlue/Test_Data02.ndf'), 
               (NAME = N'Test_Data03', FILENAME = N'/mnt/WDBlue/Test_Data03.ndf'), 
               (NAME = N'Test_Data04', FILENAME = N'/mnt/WDBlue/Test_Data04.ndf')
    LOG ON (NAME = N'Test_Log01', FILENAME = N'/mnt/WDBlue/Test_Log01.ldf')
    FOR ATTACH;
```